# How the bot can still show the appropriate response for the follow-up Intent even

Tags: dialogflow-es

Sure, I can help you with that. Here's the corrected text:

I have created a chatbot in Dialogue Flow with the following intent:

Intent: IBuy

Training phrases:
"I want to buy a dairy product."
"Do you sell dairy products?"
Responses:
"Which one are you interested in? We have Frisolac Gold, Nan Nestle, Physiolac, Morinaga, and Meiji."
The follow-up intent is:

Intent: Frisolac Inquiry

Training phrases:
"I want to buy Frisolac Gold."
"Do you have Frisolac?"
"I am interested in purchasing Frisolac."
Responses:
"Sure, would you like to know the price or location?"
The follow-up responses are:

Intent: Frisolac Inquiry - Follow-up

Training phrases:
"What is the price?"
"Where can I buy it?"
Responses:
"The price for Frisolac is $5."
"Frisolac is available nationwide."
However, the issue is that the follow-up intent is only triggered when the training phrases for the follow-up are matched. What if the user types a command like "I want to know the price of Frisolac" at the beginning of the conversation? How can the bot show the response for the follow-up?

Thank you for your help

e issue is that the follow-up Intent is only triggered when the user specifically mentions Frisolac in their message. If the user types a command like "I want to know the price of Frisolac" at the beginning of the conversation, the bot won't recognize it as a follow-up Intent and won't provide the appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand correctly your scenario, it is working as expected.

[Follow Up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents) are a special type of intents which works as a child of regular intents.

It means that to reach to follow-up intents you need to already be in the context of a parent intent (or in other words, follow-up intents cannot be reached directly without going through the parent intent first).